# How to create dynamic List<String>

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a List dynamically

I tried to create the List dynamically but it does not allow to create a dynamic List

```
int length = masterList.size();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
    for (Map.Entry < String, Object > entry: masterList.get(i).entrySet()) 
    {
        if(entry.getKey().startsWith("tag_"))
        {
            ArrayList<String> entry.getKey() = new ArrayList();
            tagDataList = Arrays.asList(entry.getValue().toString().split(","));
            for (String string : tagDataList) 
            {
                entry.getKey().add(string);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Input:

```
{
 "tag_fuse_type": "tag_1,tag_2"
}
```

Required Output:

```
{
 "tag_fuse_type": [
  "tag_1",
  "tag_2"
 ]
}
```

Comment: are you trying to parse JSON?

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by *It does not allow*? What is the problem, error message or undesired result?

Comment: can you explain this part of your question "it does not allow to create a dynamic List" ? Also what is the output you currently get?

Comment: @deHaar It says left side of an assignment must be a variable

Comment: this: `ArrayList<String> entry.getKey() = new ArrayList();` is not valid

Comment: @AbuBakarKhan I have masterList which contain multiple json's

Comment: @jhamon yes it's not a valid syntax do you know one

Comment: We have multiple JSON's and we are iterating over that by masterList.get(i) in a for loop

Comment: @StephenC yes sure will do that but can you please provide a solution now

Comment: You should really have a look on how maps work, especially on the key and **value** concept (yep, the emphasis is a big hint to solve your problem)

Comment: Have a closer look at the line `ArrayList<String> entry.getKey() = new ArrayList();`. Do you see any variable there (on the left side)? I don't...

Comment: @ShantulKuwar You can use GSON or Jackson libraries to easily parse this JSON. If that is the case that is.

Comment: Mate's i am iterating over a JSON and i know the syntax is List<String> list = new ArrayList(); but could you all have a look at the input and expected output please

Comment: It looks to me you believe you can convert a `Map<String, Object>` to a `Map<String, List>` this way but it will be much easier if you create a new Map and then convert each Object object to a List object and add the List object to your new Map together with the key

Comment: we need to create a arraylist with the keyname and we are getting the key in the entry.getKey()

Comment: It might be that my java is not that good but i know the syntax

Comment: requesting you all to please have a look at the question once again

Comment: No, you don't know the difference between key and value in a Map

Comment: The list object has no names, you just re-use the same key when adding the list to your new map

Comment: @JoakimDanielson trying the same suggested by you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<String, List<String>> newMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : masterList.entrySet()) {
    List<String> values = new LinkedList<>();
    if (entry.getKey().startsWith("tag_")) {
        String[] words = entry.getValue().split(",\\s*");
        Collections.addAll(values, words);
     } else {
        values.add(entry.getValue());
     }
     newMap.put(entry.getKey(), values);
}
```

One should not change the type of the map, so need to create a new map.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (entry.getKey().startsWith("tag_")) {
    ArrayList < String > list = new ArrayList();
    tagDataList = Arrays.asList(entry.getValue().toString().split(","));
    for (String string: tagDataList) {
        list.add(string);
    }
    tagsMap.put(entry.getKey(), list);
}
```